# How to shorten 'if, else' statement in python?

Tags: python, if-statement

I'd like to shorten my `if, elif, else` statement, Here's what it looks :

```
transparency == False
if transparency == 'true':
    transparency = True
elif transparency == 'false':
    transparency = False
else:
    transparency = True
```

And here's what I tried :

```
transparency == False
transparency == 'true' ? True: False #boolean type
```

I thought it'd work like the javascript shorthand, am I wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are overcomplicating things. The value is `False` only if originally equal to `'false'`, `True` for *anything else*:

```
transparency = transparency != 'false'
```

You otherwise got your Javascript syntax mixed up with Python; the [Python conditional expression syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#conditional-expressions) is spelled

```
<true_expr> if <test> else <false_expr>
```

Comment: I knew I was overcomplicating things that's why I was wondering how I could do it in one line :)

Answer (score 3):

Basically, if `transparency` is anything other than `'false'`, it's going to be `True`. So…

```
transparency = transparency != 'false'
```

Comment: "'id like to shorten my if, else if, else statement," You broke his concept by assuming his logic.

Comment: This is the logic OP's code expresses. The result is exactly the same.

Comment: @RoyHolzem The answer is a one liner that works in all context, it does respect my logic.